# Graph API not returning correct timezone

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to get user's timezones through the graph API `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailboxSettings` but this API is not returning correct timezone. The timezone should be UTC + 5:30 but its returning UTC. Am I missing something here ? If not then is there any other technique through which I can get the correct timezone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graph returns whatever time zone is configured in the user's mailbox. If it's set incorrectly there, Graph will return the incorrect value.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @JasonJohnston, now I'm getting the correct timezone after configuring outlook but I'm not able to get other user's timezone. I used this graph API (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/mailboxSettings) but it's returning this `{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
        "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-09-08T07:05:00",
        }
    }
}` One more thing to note that I am a global admininstrator for the organization

Comment: Do you have the `MailboxSettings.Read` permission scope in your access token?

Comment: Yes @Jason Johnston

Comment: Oh I saw you said "other user". Yeah, you can't do that without app-only permissions.

Comment: app-only permissions as in? can you please elaborate

Comment: You can have two types of access tokens: either you have a signed-in user and a user token, or you have a token for the app itself (an app-only token). App-only requires a tenant admin to grant consent and gives access to all mailboxes in the tenant. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service